# Rails: Create dynamic amount of relationships upon creating a new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

In our app, a User can join a Bet through memberships.  Each Bet can have many rounds, and each Round has many players (users) based upon who is a member of the bet at the time the round is created.

A round has many players through contracts (relationship between Round and User).  Basically, I want to be able to create a new Round and automatically create a Contract for each user who is a member of the bet.  Members can join and leave bets, any only be part of the rounds that were created while they had a Membership to the Bet.

I'm new to Rails, and can't think of a way to automatically make a contract relationship for each user who has a membership to the bet.  Any ideas would really be appreciated!!

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
#
  has_many :agree_members,   -> { where(memberships: { accepted: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) }, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :against_members, -> { where(memberships: { accepted: true }).where(memberships: { against: true }) },  through: :memberships, source: :user
#
  has_many :agree_requesters,   -> { where(memberships: { accepted: false }).where(memberships: { against: false }) }, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :against_requesters, -> { where(memberships: { accepted: false }).where(memberships: { against: true }) },  through: :memberships, source: :user

  def members
    agree_members | against_members
  end
#
  def requests
    agree_requesters | against_requesters
  end

  has_many :rounds
end
```

============

```
class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bet 

  has_many :contracts, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :potential_winners, -> { where(contracts: { agrees: true, agree_wins: true, signed: false }) }, through: :contracts, source: :user
  has_many :potential_losers, -> { where(contracts: { agrees: true, agree_wins: false, signed: false }) }, through: :contracts, source: :user

  has_many :winners, -> { where(contracts: { agrees: true, agree_wins: true, signed: true }) }, through: :contracts, source: :user
  has_many :losers, -> { where(contracts: { agrees: true, agree_wins: false, signed: true }) }, through: :contracts, source: :user

end
```

==============

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# BETS (and bet memberships)
  has_many :memberships

  has_many :agree_bets,   -> { where(memberships: { accepted: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :memberships, source: :bet
  has_many :against_bets, -> { where(memberships: { accepted: true }).where(memberships: { against: true }) },   through: :memberships, source: :bet

  has_many :pending_bets, -> { where(memberships: { accepted: false }) }, through: :memberships, source: :bet

  def active_bets
    agree_bets | against_bets
  end

  def joined_bets
    active_bets | pending_bets
  end

# ROUNDS (and contracts)
has_many :contracts

#IGNORE THIS LOGIC, NOT SET UP YET AND NOT RELEVANT
has_many :agree_maybe_wins,     -> { where(contracts: { agree: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :contracts, source: :round
has_many :against_maybe_wins,   -> { where(contracts: { agree: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :contracts, source: :round

has_many :agree_maybe_loses,    -> { where(contracts: { agree: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :contracts, source: :round
has_many :against_maybe_loses,  -> { where(contracts: { agree: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :contracts, source: :round


has_many :agree_wins,   -> { where(contracts: { agree: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :contracts, source: :round
has_many :against_wins, -> { where(contracts: { agree: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :contracts, source: :round


has_many :agree_losses,   -> { where(contracts: { agree: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :contracts, source: :round
has_many :against_losses, -> { where(contracts: { agree: true }).where(memberships: { against: false }) },  through: :contracts, source: :round



def potential_wins
  agree_maybe_wins | against_maybe_wins
end

def wins
  agree_wins | against_wins
end

def potential_losses
  agree_maybe_wins | against_maybe_wins
end

def losses
  agree_wins | against_wins
end



end
```

Comment: I would like to keep a Round's contracts completely separate from a Bet's memberships, because someone could join a bet by creating a membership, play a few rounds, and leave the bet by destroying their membership.  If a bet member destroys their membership, I would still like them to have a history with the bet through their contracts with all the rounds they participated in

Answer (score 1):

One approach here would be a `has_many :through` relationship. If I understand your application correctly, your model relations could be roughly summarized as:

*User -> Contract -> Round -> Bet*

Conceived of this way, you can then deal with :memberships as an alias in the `Round` model.

```
Class Round
  has_many :memberships, class_name: "User", through: :contracts
end
```

With the `Contract` model of the format looking containing `user_id` and `round_id`, each time a user is involved in a `Round`, you would create a `Contract` model to represent that involvement as a "member". In other words, creating a contract wouldn't be an additional step, but rather the fundamental action of entering a user into a round. Specifically, you could write the following:

```
class User
  def self.add_to_round(round_id)
    Contract.create(user_id: self.id, round_id: round_id)
  end
end
```

and then query things like `Round.first.members` or `User.first.rounds`.

For convenience, you may also wish to create another `has_many :through` relationship that allows you to query directly from Users to Bets (or the reverse). This would look like:

```
class User
  has_many :rounds, through: :contracts
  has_many :bets, through: :rounds
end
```

With both of these relationships in place, you should then be able to call `User.first.bets` to get all bets that a user has been involved in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  As my code stands now, my model relations would be

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  As my code stands now, my model relations would be Bet has many users through memberships, and a bet also has many rounds (directly, no relationship model used).  A round has many users through contracts.  I would like users to be able to join and leave bets (create and destroy memberships), but always have a record of the rounds they participated in while they're members of the bet (want to maintain all contracts even if memberships are deleted).  I'm very new to rails, does your suggestion allow for this funcitonality?

Comment: In other words, each round is made from a bet `@round = @bet.rounds.build(..)`, and all the contracts of the round are determined by the members (users) the bet currently has (through memberships).  At the time the round is created, how do I make a contract for each member (User) the bet has (through relationships) ?

Comment: Keeping in mind that a bet's members will come and go, but each round's contracts should not be affected by someone leaving the bet